# Matlab operation without loops

Tags: matlab

I have a matrix `distance = [d11,d12,d13,d14;d15;...;dn1,dn2,dn3,dn4,dn5];` and a vector `index(n,1)`. The value of index are between 1 and 5.

I want to get the sum of the distance according to the index if a vector R(1,5).

An example :

`distance = [1,2,4,1,2 ; 4,5,6,1,6 ; 7,8,9,5,8] and index = [1;1;3]`

So, I want `R(1) = 1+4 = 5, R(2) = 0,  R(3) = 9, and R(4) = R(5) = 0`

The condition is to not use a loop over 1:5 with a if condition in order to minimise the time of execution if there are billions of points.

Maybe it is possible with arrayfun, but I don't succeed.

Best regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To find out which elements you have to sum up, you can use the [`bsxfun`](https://mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to create a matrix containing a `1` if the value is relevant, and a `0` otherwise. This can done with

```
bsxfun(@eq, index, 1:5)
```

which will create a vector `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]` and do an element-wise comparison between `index` and that vector. The result of this function is

```
ans =

     1     0     0     0     0
     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0
```

Now you can multiply this matrix with the `distance` matrix (element-wise!) and finally sum over each column:

```
>> R = sum(bsxfun(@eq, index, 1:5) .* distance, 1);
```

which results in

```
R =

     5     0     9     0     0
```

Comment: Thank you.
Now, I would like to normalise each value of R. Can you help me ?
I have some difficulty to work without loop ...

Comment: Do you mean normalize `R` to have a length of 1, i.e. `R(1) = 5/14` and `R(3)=9/14` in your example?

Comment: I find the solution : 
 A = bsxfun(@eq, index, 1:5)
    R = sum(bsxfun(@eq, index, 1:5) .* distance, 1)./sum(A(:,1:5));